# WPML redirection for homepage (en-en) wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wpml

Is anyone here using WPML?

I want to remove the redirection of the homepage from

https://homepage.com/en-en/

to

https://homepage.com

I have disabled the *"Use directory for default language"* but it is still redirecting to en-en
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5Cj2.png]

but still there is an error
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDNAF.png]

Comment: Did you rebuild the WordPress Permalinks after disabling the directory? 
If you have hardcoded links pointing to "https://homepage.com/en-en/", you will need to change them as well.

Comment: is it possible to just hide it or hide en-en from showing on homepage?